# Secondary Index in OrientDB

Tags: indexing, orientdb, secondary-indexes

Is there a way to specify a secondary index in OrientDB?

I need something that have all the documents references that have a specified field (like `indexable=true`).

Answer (score 2):

All indexes in [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org) are like the secondary of RDBMS (the primary doesn't exists because the RID is auto-assigned). So just create indexes following the documentation: https://github.com/nuvolabase/orientdb/wiki/Indexes